# Not able to connect to MySQL database using PHP-FPM

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I recently installed php7.4-fpm (FPM/FastCGI). But I'm not able to connect to MySQL database.

I'm using the following configuration. Note my database has no password. Tried 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'http://127.0.0.1:3306', '127.0.0.1:3306', in **DB_SERVER** setting but no luck.

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'republic');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
}
?>
```

Comment: Using die() is great to say that something went wrong, but it doesn't tell you what went wrong. I would suggest using something like a try catch to see exactly what is causing the connection not to go through. Also since you've switched to php7.4-fpm, did you ensure that you have the right mods disabled/ enabled?

Comment: `mysqli_error()` handling would be a good start to understand what went wrong. *Oops! Something went wrong.* is just useless.

Comment: Thanks after MySQL secure installation things started working.